# Bootstrap 3 tabs and open first tab on page load

Tags: tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not able to get open first tab on page load. Code below.

```
    <ul id="rowTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_a">Tab A</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_b">Tab B</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_c">Tab C</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_d">Tab D</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
             <div id="tab_a" class="tab-pane fade active">
             Tab A inner
             </div>
             <div id="tab_b" class="tab-pane fade">
             Tab B inner              
             </div>
             <div id="tab_c" class="tab-pane fade">
             Tab C inner       
             </div>
             <div id="tab_d" class="tab-pane fade">
             Tab D inner
             </div>
   </div>
```

and jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#rowTab a:first').tab('show');
    });    
</script>
```

Any clue why is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove the `fade` class from the first tab's content..

```
<div id="tab_a" class="tab-pane active">
    Tab A inner
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/129046

Answer (score 6):

And working version with the `fade`

```
<div id="tab_a" class="tab-pane active fade in">
    Tab A inner
</div>
```

Baghoo - Thanks for pointing me to what is causing issue

Comment: Wow, right there it is in the documentation for the fade effect (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#fade-effect). I completely overlooked that.